# Having trouble concerning error handling with react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, react-query

So I am using useMutation with a form, and attempting to handle errors. When the request fails, the `error` variable does not update until the request fails for a second time. https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-dewdney-jodpp?file=/src/App.js is an example of what I am describing. I'm pretty new to development, so any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated. :D

Comment: I works for me, I click it and see the error?

Answer (score -5):

You should use the `isError` instead of `error` to detect the error state.